# html file open&save jquery tag replace

Tags: php, jquery

To change the tag specified arbitrarily open the file, I'm trying to save the file again.

Sorry I used a translator
How can a jquery tag replace...?

test.html ↓

```
<banner_0101>
        <div class="banner"><a href="#" rel="external"><img src="test.jpg" ></a></div>
</banner_0101>  

<banner_0127>
    <div class="banner"><img src="http://test.jpg" ></div>
</banner_0127>
```

test.php ↓

```
<div id="form">
    <form action="testok.php" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="cate">CATE_NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" name="cate" id="cate">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="href">A href </label>
            <input type="text" name="href" id="href">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="imgsrc">Img src</label>
            <input type="text" name="imgsrc" id="imgsrc">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

ex ) 
POST Value
test.ok ->
$_POST['cate'] -> banner_0101
$_POST['href'] -> /test1.php
$_POST['imgsrc'] -> testok.jpg

test.html ↓

<banner_0101>
        <div class="banner"><a href="/test1.php" rel="external"><img src="testok.jpg" ></a></div>
</banner_0101>

**How do I resolve this problem?**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many solution (finding the specific banner and replacing the DOM using `.find()` and `.replaceWith())` can be like this without going to PHP and just in jquery add this in your script:

```
$('#form form').on('submit', function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); //Stops your form default behavior

  banner = $('#cate').val(); //banner value
  link = $('#href').val(); //link
  imgsrc = $('#imgsrc').val(); //img src

  newDom = $('<'+ banner +'>').html($('<div>' , {'class' : 'banner'}).append($('<a>' ,{'href' : link }).append($('<img>',{'src': imgsrc })))); //your new HTML

  $('body').find(banner).replaceWith(newDom); //find the specific banner and replace existing banner with new DOM


});
```